Where is the error log when "Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file ... failed"?
(spin-off from this question)
Suppose I try to configure a project which uses CUDA, i.e. invokes
enable_language(CUDA)

in the CMakeLists.txt, and when configuring, I am told:
... etc. etc. ...
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:838 (message):
  Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file
  "CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.

  Compiler:

  Build flags:

  Id flags: --keep;--keep-dir;tmp -v`

"CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.

Compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing

Toolkit/CUDA/v11.6/bin/nvcc.exe

Build flags:

Id flags: --keep;--keep-dir;tmp -v


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:8 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:53 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.30/Modules/CMakeDetermineCUDACompiler.cmake:131 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (enable_language)

Ok, fair enough, it's an error - but I need to know what the error was! Where do I find the log of errors, or the standard error stream, for that compilation attempt? Assume I build with cmake -B C:\Path\To\BuildDir.

Usually, compilation failures for feature detection are logged somewhere in the CMake build directory. Do you see a CMakeError.log file?

@AnisLadram: Not my CMake output, actually. Are the errors the compiler emitted supposed to be in there?

Apparently starting CMake 3.26 it's here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-configure-log.7.html

@AnisLadram: SO, the error the compiler emitted would appear in that file? Great, make that an answer :-)

Just posted an answer, thanks!

Starting CMake 3.26, and based on this section of the CMake documentation, configure-time errors should be located at:

${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/CMakeConfigureLog.yaml

For completeness, before CMake 3.26 (3.25 and older), the error is logged in a file named CMakeError.log. See this issue for more information.

... and that should contain the error the compiler emitted?

Yep correct. CMake feature detection is used by CMake to evaluate which features are available within your compiler. In order to achieve this, it builds files with a given feature, and simply checks if it compiles or not. See documentation for try_compile for more info. Based on the same doc, passing the NO_LOG flag to try_compile disables logging. Thanks!
